# Naker.back with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, interactive, react-lifecycle-hooks

[Naker.Back Documentations](https://doc.naker.io/Back/Framework.html)

I came across an [article](https://medium.com/naker/6-cool-interactive-website-backgrounds-how-to-make-them-13e585dd0015) that uses Naker.back to make interactive backgrounds so I decided to give it a try in my portfolio website that I plan on using MERN stack to build. I was planning to use my [interactive background created](https://harbor.naker.io/back/604e105c21593400046da4a9/) and embed it into my React component.

[This is the file structure for my home page now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwlSS.png)

This is the code for Background.js that I copied and edited the value based on the documentation provided and will be exported into Home.js as JSX

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from './Background.module.css'

const script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "https://d23jutsnau9x47.cloudfront.net/back/v1.0.9/viewer.js";
script.async = true;
document.body.appendChild(script);

class Background extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
    window.nakerback.render({
        container: document.getElementById('container'),
        particle: {
            direction1: {x: 0,y: 0,z: 0},
            direction2: {x: 0,y: -100,z: -100},
            life: 5,
            power: 0.02,
            texture: "https://res.cloudinary.com/naker-io/image/upload/v1566560053/flare_01.png",
            number: 2000,
            colorStart: [251,251,251,0],
            colorEnd: [4,72,132,0.52],
            sizeStart: 1.15,
            sizeEnd: 2.3
        },
        environment: {
            gradient: 'horizontol',
            sensitivity: 0.8,
            backgroundTop: [40,4,107,1],
            backgroundBottom: [1,18,51,1]
        }
    });
}
    render(){ 
    return <div className={styles.background} id="container"></div>
    };
}

export default Background;
```

Home.js code that will be exported into App.js as component for the route:

```
import React from 'react';
import Background from '../components/Background'

const Home = () => {
    return(
        <div>
            <Background/>
            <h1>Home</h1>
        </div>
        )
};

export default Home;
```

Error Message was thrown back:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined

```
   9 | class Background extends Component {
  10 | 
  11 |     componentDidMount() {
> 12 |         window.nakerback.render({
  13 |             container: document.getElementById('container'),
  14 |             particle: {
  15 |                 direction1: {x: 0,y: 0,z: 0},
```

Comment: Are you sure this `nakerback` library is loaded when the react code runs? Looks like it's not

Comment: I have no idea. I followed the documentation. Copied exactly what was written.

Comment: They say this: Reminder, if you do have access to your head tag you can just put in it:

`<script data-who=' Made with naker.io ' src='https://d23jutsnau9x47.cloudfront.net/back/v1.0.9/viewer.js' ></script>`

Comment: Since it is your portfolio and you have access to `<head>`, I'd just put it there

Comment: Alright I'll give it a try